# Firebase - Trying to retrieve data of each user into a list

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each user in my app can send and get friend requests. When the user checks his friends requests, I want the app to go through each user who sent him a friend request and retrieve his information from the `Realtime Database`.

This is my code in order to accomplish this:

```
 public void check_For_Friends_And_Requests(){
        String loggedUser=SaveSharedPreference.getLoggedEmail(getApplicationContext());


            final DatabaseReference mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            final DatabaseReference userRef=mDatabase.child("Users").child(loggedUser);

            userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        final List<User> friendRequestsReceived_UserList=new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child("friend_requests_received").getChildren()) {

                            final String senderEmail=postSnapshot.getKey();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    senderEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (senderEmail!=null){
                                mDatabase.child("Users").child(senderEmail).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        friendRequestsReceived_UserList.add(
                                                new User(
                                                        senderEmail,
                                                        dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class),
                                                       dataSnapshot.child("level").getValue(Integer.class),
                                                        dataSnapshot.child("skill").getValue(Double.class)));

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }

                        UserListAdapter friendRequestsReceived_Adapter =
                        new UserListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.friend_requests_received_listview_row,
                                friendRequestsReceived_UserList);

                        friendRequestsReceived_ListView.setAdapter(friendRequestsReceived_Adapter);

                    }

                    else
                    connectionErrorGoToMain();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    connectionErrorGoToMain();
                }
            });


    }
```

I have in this code 2 `ValueEventListeners`. I add the user information to the list in the inner one. **The problem is that the list is empty at the end of this process.**

I would like to fill a list view with this information using these lines:

```
 UserListAdapter friendRequestsReceived_Adapter =
                        new UserListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.friend_requests_received_listview_row,
                                friendRequestsReceived_UserList);

                        friendRequestsReceived_ListView.setAdapter(friendRequestsReceived_Adapter);
```

When I put them inside the innner listener, it works fine, but I don't want to set the adapter for each user in the list, only after the `for` loop.

I'm attaching a screenshot with my database structure (I don't need to get all of the parameters):

[image]

Comment: I need you to see your Firebase data structure

Comment: @ILAYS_Kerbal I've added a screenshot

Comment: all you can do is ....Store List with each object like

Class use{
List<FirendRequest> friendReuqest=new ArrayList();
String name;
}
and in your Ondata change Listener do a nested query on friendReqest child and pass dataSnapshot to it and then setvalue to your model
First get list and then add list in your model and store it in userList
dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class),

Answer (score 1):

The list is empty because you are declaring `friendRequestsReceived_UserList` outside the inner `onDataChange()` method. This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method which is called before you are adding those new objects to the list. So, in order to solve this, just move the declaration of the list inside the inner `onDataChange()` method like this:

```
if (senderEmail!=null){
mDatabase.child("Users").child(senderEmail).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final List<User> friendRequestsReceived_UserList=new ArrayList<>(); //Moved here

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    friendRequestsReceived_UserList.add(
        new User(
            senderEmail,
            dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class),
                dataSnapshot.child("level").getValue(Integer.class),
            dataSnapshot.child("skill").getValue(Double.class)));
            UserListAdapter friendRequestsReceived_Adapter =

     new UserListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.friend_requests_received_listview_row, friendRequestsReceived_UserList);
     friendRequestsReceived_ListView.setAdapter(friendRequestsReceived_Adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

As you probably see, i set the adapter also inside the inner method. If you want to use that list outside the `onDataChange()` i suggest you reading my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: If I'm gonna set the adapter in the inner onDataChange(), I'm gonna set it inside the "for" loop, and actually set it for every object in it. I'd like to set it only once, after the "for" loop, when the list is full of objects.

Comment: You cannot achieve this with your database structure because you need to use nested queries, which means that you need to load data asynchronous twice. If you use that list outside the `onDataChange()` method (doesn't matther which) it will always be null. You have 2 possibilities. To use my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange), which works perfectly or to change your database structure in which only one query is needed.

Comment: I don't understand, does your answer in this post help me with putting the adapter after the "for" loop? If it does, I don't get it. This is my attempt to implement the code from the code in my code: https://pastebin.com/fgWhNpDv

Comment: I didn't say to set the adapter either inside or either outside the for loop. I just said that you need to declare and use that `ArrayList` inside `onDataChange()` method because otherwise is null. Because that `ArrayList` contains information just inside that method, setting the adapter must take place also there.